# Reading and setting values to a variable from a file in MatLab

Tags: matlab

so I have a file, data.dat that I have imported into my Matlab:

```
myData=importdata('data.dat');
```

and it has the layout of showing time, followed by 2 lots of 3 values eg.

```
0.000    
   0.744
   0.313
   0.982

   -2.19
   0.383
   0.324

0.313
   -2.09
   2.883
   0.827

   0.875
   -0.293
   1.11
```

Is it possible for me to be able to assign the first 3 values of every 'set' to a variable so I am able to plot it?

(e.g. I want         0.744, 0.313, 0.982 and -2.09,2.883,0.827 assigned to a variable - or even 3 variables (as these represent values in the(x,y,z)-plane)

please could someone offer some help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are completely confident about the structure of the data, you can just hard code a little `for` loop to construct a matrix out of the dataset:

```
>> x=[0, 0.744, 0.313, 0.982, -2.19, 0.383, 0.324, 0.313, -2.09, 2.883, 0.827, 0.875, -0.293, 1.11];
>> for n=1:length(x)/7
lots(n,:) = x((n-1)*7+1:n*7);
end
```

Then you can just index the values you want from the rows of values you are interested in. For example:

```
>> figure
>> plot(lots(1,2:5))
```